# Is it possible to know the Rect of visible area in a View when scaled in Android?

Tags: android

If I have a view that I use 'ScaleGestureDetector`to detect the scale, and apply scale factor to the view. When the View is zoomed in, only portion of the view is visible. That's what I'm curious about. Is it possible to get that area in a`Rect`?

I don't have a code sample. It's gonna be something like below. Black rect is the screen and red rect is the content. When content is scaled, it is only partially visible. Is it possible to get the green area?
[image]

Comment: Provide some more info like screenshots of your view, some code sample etc. to understand the problem better

Comment: added a drawing to help with visualization.